# Spring MVC with Java annotation configuration doesn't found Javascript and CSS files in resource folder

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm creating a web application using `Spring MVC 4.2.5.RELEASE`, I have this basic java annotation configuration without using web-xml files or context.xml files.

The application works fine so far loading the views when I access them in the browser, but the CSS and JavaScript files don't load, it says in the google console that the resources are not found and it shows 404 error code.

Here is my JSP where I put the path in the `src` tag (index.jsp):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:set var="cp" value="${pageContext.request.servletContext.contextPath}" scope="request" />


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Spring 4 Web MVC via Annotations</title>

        <script src="${cp}/resources/js/js.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${cp}/resources/css/site.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/site.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/site.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/site.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Spring 4 Web MVC via Annotations</h4>
        Spring says: <span class="blue">${msg}</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

if you look at the code I tried calling them using four different ways like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${cp}/resources/css/site.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/site.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/site.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/site.css" />
```

but still it always says source not found.

I know that everything that is inside `WEB-INF` folder it's private, but I have read a lot of tutorials and they all have their resources inside that folder and they configure this method in the Config.JAVA file be able to use them.

This is the *Resource Handler* in my Java configuration:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

Here are my configuration classes. I'm using Java annotations and I don't have any `context.xml` or `web.xml` file

My Config class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"config", "controllers"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class ConfigMVC extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

My `WebInitializer` class

```
public class WebInicializar implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {        
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();  
        ctx.register(ConfigMVC.class);  
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);    
        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));  
        servlet.addMapping("/");  
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }

}
```

My Controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(ModelMap map) {
        map.put("msg", "Hello Spring 4 Web MVC!");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

and here is my project structure

```
MyWebAppName
--Web Pages
  --WEB-INF
    --jsp
         index.jsp
    --resources
      --js
         js.js
      --css
         site.css
--Source Packages
  --config
      ConfigMVC.java
      WebInitializaer.java
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `WEB-INF` prefix to the *Resource Location*:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
```

Comment: Ok I added that to Resource Handler, but how should I put the path in the src="",   also is there a way to put the path without using the jstl value??
like this "../resources" etc, without using {cp}

Comment: Same paths as before, we're just changed the physical location

Comment: And i'm not an expert in jsp and jstl but by adding `WEB-INF`, your spring side of the story would be fine

Answer (score 0):

Two points to note, as mentioned in previous answer by @Ali Dehgani,

1. Change directory structure to

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
```

This is necessary as your resources folder is not is direct deployed folder, rather is inside WEB_INF.

2. Change the link tag to something like this to use Spring:Url tag:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<spring:url value="/resourses/css/site.css"/>' />
```

I solved a similar issue with these two changes. Thanks :)

EDIT: This link could help to understand the configuration:
https://www.boraji.com/spring-mvc-5-static-resources-handling-example